# Msbuild Issue in Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am new in CI/CD deployment and I want to CI/Cd of ASP.net Project in Jenkins

Note : this project is working fine VS 2017

I am Building abc.sln with command line arrgument /p:OutDir=c:\Samplelocation\;Configuration=release

when I am building the abc.sln then I did not get the Build code as in VS 2017

It gives all directory which is on (Bitbucket) but I need the compile code include .git and .gitignore
I have checked in c:]Samplelocation then it gives me exe file

can anyone please help me on the same.

Comment: The `.git` folder contains all the information that is necessary for your project in version control and all the information about commits, remote repository address, etc.The `.gitignore` file is a text file that tells Git which files or folders to ignore in a project. So they are not the content of the project to compile and have nothing to do with msbuild compilation. Just the version control information stored in the project folder. You do not need to worry about it during build process.

Comment: My Project is building  but it shows error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "bin\RoundInsp.dll" because it was not found. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\HCFC\HCF.Web\HCF.Web.csproj] It gives me this error

Comment: Can one tell me that how can i give the C drive path in Drive in jenkins during archive